# How can I change the background color of a <div> element using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How would I change the color of the tag

I'm trying to make a dark mode bookmarklet to cover all of the html elements change

```
document.body.style.background = 'black';
```

This changes the color of the body so what would I do for

I tried

```
document.body.style.background = 'black';
document.body.style.color = 'white';
document.div.style.background = 'black';
document.div.style.color = 'white';
```

but I cant seem to get change the color of the div

Comment: Can you provide more details providing your source code HTML please

Comment: @GoodCoder I have updated the code in the answer. Try that

Comment: You need to implicitly select the div using a selector and a method that correlates with that selector. If your div has a class of 'my-div' you can target that elements node list using a class name => `document.querySelectorAll('.my-div')`, or an HTML List `document.getElementsByClassName('my-div')` or maybe an id of `my-div` then you could target it using `div.getElementsById('my-div')`. Look up these built in JS methods on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) look on left sidebar, so you understand what they return and how to handle them in terms of looping,

Answer (score 0):

if the `div` has an `id`, you can do this:

```js
document.getElementById('your-div-id').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
document.getElementById('your-div-id').style.color = 'white';
```

```html
<div id="your-div-id">
Dark Mode
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select the elements, then you can apply styling on that. Here is a an example snippet:-

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
// Give background color to body element
body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

const div = document.querySelector('div');
// Give text color to div element
div.style.color = 'white';
```

```html
<body>
<div>Hey I am here</div>
</body>
```

I used **querySelector()** to select the elements in the above example. There are [many articles](https://blog.bitsrc.io/dom-selectors-explained-70260049aaf0) that can explain how to select the elements from DOM.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to apply a separate class for dark mode:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

body.dark {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor.
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
<button>Toggle Dark Mode</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access div elements this way "document.div".
You must select the element(s) you want to modify.
If you want to modify a single element you must select it with document.getElementById("id")
or document.querySelector("") select by "#id" or class ".className" or tag "tagName".
To modify several elements you must select them all:
document.querySelectorAll()

You can see all the examples below.

```js
// Get one div by "id"
const divId = document.querySelector("#id")
// Select all divs
const allDiv = document.querySelectorAll("div")
// Selects all divs with a specific class
const greyDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".grey")

document.body.style.background = 'black';
// Iterate through the div array with the forEach() function
allDiv.forEach((div) => {
  // Assign background and color for each div
  div.style.background = '#606060';
  div.style.color = "white"
})

divId.style.background = 'red';
divId.style.color = "yellow"

// Same procedure for divs select by "class name"
greyDivs.forEach((div) => {
  div.style.background = '#303030';
  div.style.color = "#ff4d4d"
})
```

```css
div {margin-top: 15px;}
```

```html
<div id="id">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus reiciendis temporibus sed deserunt eos perferendis ipsum consectetur doloribus, eaque voluptatem numquam cum doloremque rem nisi. Libero nam laborum est mollitia!
</div>
<div class="grey">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis minima, tenetur ut accusamus autem. Natus ducimus nihil saepe nemo minus quos earum, ex eos est et beatae repudiandae qui molestias.
</div>
<div class="grey">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero voluptates sed voluptatem laboriosam nisi et ea numquam earum excepturi perspiciatis? Harum eius beatae accusamus earum, voluptatum sit maiores fugit minus.
</div>
<div class="grey">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum, officiis, error! Ea eos ab, et architecto officiis minima. Placeat, quos quas doloribus libero, porro earum culpa voluptatem corporis consectetur fugit!
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita perspiciatis cumque atque vel reiciendis, quos totam repudiandae iusto unde, deserunt a, omnis magni. Asperiores officia quisquam cum, facere magnam itaque.
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus iure minus sequi, a sapiente soluta corrupti et facilis hic. Accusamus impedit non expedita aperiam cum, dolore maxime provident quaerat rerum?
</div>
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus possimus necessitatibus facilis vitae unde, assumenda nisi quam quod eligendi iste reiciendis vero, quae ipsa totam at deleniti nostrum aperiam et.
</div>
```